# After removing nodes from Azure service fabric cluster, cluster status is ‘Upgrade service unreachable’

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-scale-set

5 node Azure VMSS (which is associated with Azure Service Fabric Cluster) has been 'scaled in' to 1 node. After this 'scale in' process, VMSS is up & running and healthy.

But the Azure Service Fabric Cluster (which uses this VMSS)  entered in to ‘Upgrade service unreachable’ status & it shows '0' node & '0' application. Also can't able to access the service fabric explorer web page.

Even after 'scaling out' VMSS back to 5 nodes, no change in service fabric status but still remains in inoperable state. How to bring back Azure service fabric to operable state without rebuild the cluster from the scratch? What would be root cause for Service Fabric inoperable state, is it because of scaling down its VMSS to 1 node? (or) because of its couple of 'seed' nodes got removed?

Tried out deallocating & restarting the VMSS node, upgraded VM size in VMSS from 'Standard_DS1_v1’ to 'Standard_DS1_v2’ but no luck

Service Fabric Version: 7.1.458.9590

Exception:

**Connect-ServiceFabricCluster** : No cluster endpoint is reachable, please check Error if there is connectivity/firewall/DNS issue.

Comment: What is your current [reliability level setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-capacity#reliability-characteristics-of-the-cluster)?

Comment: Reliability Tier - bronze